# How to download and delete a file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i want to delete and download a upload file from my database 
i already upload and show it now i want to download and delete the files which iupload
Here is my controller showupload.php

```
<?php class Showupload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{

    $this->load->model('showuploadmodel');
    $data['query']=$this->showuploadmodel->showfile(); 
    $this->load->view('showupload_view',$data);


}
 public function delete_upload($file_id) {
    $this->load->showupload('showuploadmodel');
    $data = $this->showuploadmodel->delete($file_id);
    $this->load->view('showupload_view',$data);
}
public function download($filelink)
{
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents("$filelink"); // Read the file's link
force_download($filelink, $data);            
}
}
?>
```

and this is my view show_upload_view.php

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('tnavbar.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Show Upload</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class='well'>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th><h1>File Name</h1></th>
    <th><h1>Date</h1></th>
    <th><h1>Action</h1></th>   
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($query as $row){
 echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h2>". $row->filename ."</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>". $row->date ."</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h2>".Download|Delete."</h2></td>";
    //now how can i make download and delete from my database
    //my database contains filename,fileid,filelink     
  echo "</tr>";  
}
?>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

now how can i make download and delete from my database
my database contains filename,fileid,filelink

Comment: how to add download helper and file helper in a button ????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading you should use Download Helper

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

```
$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/photo.jpg"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'myphoto.jpg';

force_download($name, $data);
```

And for deleting you have a delete function in File Helper

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

```
delete_files('./path/to/directory/');
```

Comment: But how i add this into a button or link?????? please help i am new in codeigniter